# SkyDrive file upload via net 2.0

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, onedrive

I want to upload files on SkyDrive (the folder is public) using the .Net Framework 2.0 System.Net library. (with winform or console project)

the Skydrive Folder is `"<http://sdrv.ms/P0lta5>"`

I googled for result and i found some code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] up = wc.UploadFile(@"<http://sdrv.ms/P0lta5>", @"d:/1.jpg");
```

But using this code my file not get uploaded to given folder.

(any code sample with `WebClient`, `HttpWebRequest` will be helpful).

Comment: I would rather use the [SkyDrive API](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2012/04/25/skydrive-apis-bring-your-data-to-any-app-any-platform-any-device.aspx).

Comment: @UweKeim: Currently the only [official Microsoft managed API for SkyDrive is for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/default.aspx). There is also an [unofficial managed API on CodePlex](http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/) but it still has beta status.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following api,

http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/